# Mapping External IP Address to Secondary IP for GCP High Availability Setup

Tags: google-cloud-platform, high-availability, vpc

We are seeking assistance in mapping a secondary IP address to an external IP address on a data interface. While we have successfully added an external IP address to the primary IP address on the data interface, our goal is to assign an external IP address to the secondary IP address. This is necessary for GCP High Availability (HA) to utilize traffic on the virtual IP (VIP).

If anyone has knowledge of how to achieve this mapping of an external IP address to a secondary IP address, your insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Tried all the possible way to map the secondary ip to external ip, but didnt find any way.